# IE7 Absolute Position starts at top of line as opposed to other browsers

Tags: html, css, css-position

I created a fiddle that exemplifies the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/vZtBb/

This is working exactly as I want it, but the problem is that in IE7 the absolutely positioned span (`hover-tooltip-container`) starts at the top of the line instead of at the bottom like it does in the other browsers.  If you add a border to `hover-tooltip-container`, you can see this.

This is a problem because I want the tooltip to go up, but the anchor to still be exposed.  You should be able to mouse over the tooltip as well, but the gap in IE7 makes this impossible.

If there is any way to get the `hover-tooltip-container` span to start in the same place on the line in IE7, IE8, and FFX, that would be perfect.

Javascript is not a solution.

Comment: Side-issue:  Your 100% width does not take the padding or borders into account.  Example, in Safari, the tooltip is always wider than the window (with horizontal scroll-bars) no matter how wide you make the window.

Comment: @Sparky672 thank you.  The 100% width container should be inside another container of relatively low width, so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by having the "container" element float left and have relative position.  This achieves the appearance of breaking out of containers but still provides a reference for the tooltip to go up from.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple thing you could do with the code you already have, is add a star hack to adjust the `bottom` rule within `.hover-tooltip`, for IE7.

```
.hover-tooltip {
   display: block;
   padding: 15px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   bottom: 1em;
   *bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px outset #c0c0c0;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

However, the double, nested absolute positions of `.hover-tooltip-container` and `.hover-tooltip` seem unnecessary.

Comment: +1 Good diagnosis, and best solution (under the circumstances).

Comment: @Bart I'd like to avoid the star hack, but we'll see.  The double nested positions don't seem necessary at first and may cause the problem, but they are in fact necessary for what I'm doing because the anchor may appear inline in some other text, but the tooltip still has to extend all the way to the left of the page AND up relative to the anchor.  This requires another "invisible" element wrapping it to get the reference of where to go up from.

Answer (score 0):

I did something quite different (also renamed your classes, to much of a hassle to play with those looooooooooong name).

http://jsfiddle.net/vZtBb/16/

I removed the nested absolute positionning : They are the one causing the issue, since element in absolute position are taken out of context. So, 2 solo, nested absolute positionned element means that one element is in *nothing* (glitchy and really not wanted).

Instead of that, I placed your tooltip box in absolute, but made it start higher than the anchor by use of a negative position (`top:-70px`). It's sketchy a bit, but you should get my point.

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting this after the .hover-tooltip div:

```
<div class="clear fix"></div>
```

and this css:

```
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display: block;clear: both;visibility: hidden;line-height: 0;height: 0;}

.clearfix {display: inline-block; }

html[xmlns] .clearfix {display: block; }* html .clearfix {height: 1%; }
```